# How can I add a button inside var content page code-behind using Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: button, xamarin.forms, code-behind, content-pages

How can I add a button inside var content page in code-behind? I'm trying to make a list view of content pages each with its own button.

```
var content = new ContentPage
              {
                   Title = EntryTitulo.Text,
                   Content = new Label
                   {
                       Text = EntryText.Text,
                       VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
                       HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,                       
                    },

                    //I want to add a button here.... 
               };
```

Comment: @The_Outsider: regarding your edit, note that the ownership form of "its" does not have an apostrophe. It's a bit of an unusual one, since we'd say "halfer's account" or "the outsider's edit" (i.e. with apostrophes). However, "it's" (with an apostrophe) is only ever a contraction i.e. "it is".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `ContentPage` can only have a single child.  If you want to add multiple children, they need to be contained in a Layout container, like a `StackLayout` or a `Grid`

```
var label = new Label { ... };
var button = new Button { ... };

var layout = new StackLayout();

layout.Children.Add(label);
layout.Children.Add(button);

Content = layout;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. God bless you